# Optimized algorithm to find all the local maximum

Tags: algorithm

I am currently looking into the time complexity of the algorithm for finding all the local maxima. According to [this](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec02.pdf), the time complexity is O(log N) for 1D array. Is it for finding out only one maxima?

What if I want to find all the maxima? Is there any way to find all of them with complexity smaller than O(N) of brute force method?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, for the array [1,2,1,2,1,2,...] there are O(n) local maxima. If you need to actually find them - the output itself is O(n).

Comment: In terms of complexity, an algorithm with complexity strictly lower that `O(n)` is impossible because the entire input cannot be read in lower time complexity. A sublinear complexity is possible only if the result does not depend on the entire input.

Comment: Is it possible to get better algorithm with less complexity? Say O(log(N)) to identify all the maxima?

Comment: The algorithm you linked to only seeks to find a local min/max not all of them. Finding all of them is O(N). Any method to find all local maximums requires either approximation (IE find no more than k local maxes) or having already read the data at least once and only provides sub-linear queries. Such as if you wanted to change a bunch of values and see what the new maximiums are. Such an algorithm could provide queries in O(log N) or better with O(N) processioning. However, it would still take O(N) to read/copy the results.

Comment: what do you mean by "all the maximum"? there is only one maximum ever. is this a theoretical question or are you actually trying to improve the performance of something?

Comment: @AndreasMüller There is only one global maximum but there can be several local maxima

Comment: @AndreasMüller I am sorry. What I mean is maxima

Comment: ah ok. you should post code btw. depending on situation you can improve your whole implementation. if you're periodically looking for maximum you could for example use ordered lists, which allow advanced search algorithms, speeding up the whole search. sorted inserts however take their time too. just a suggestion though. i think a little code always helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I stated in comments, for the counter example of `[1,2,1,2,...]` there are `O(n)` local maxima, and the output size itself is thus `O(n)`.

Another approach to prove that finding all local maxima is Omega(n) problem, goes as folloes.

First, note that finding global maximum is Omega(n) problem.

Now, we will represent the following algorithm to solve global maximum in an array `A`:

1. Find all local maxima in `A`
2. Regard the elements found in (1) as the new array `A`.
3. if size(A) > 1 - return to 1
4. else: the only element in A is the global maxima.

Correctness of the algorithm is pretty trivial, we iteratively discard elements, and the global maximum is never discarded.

Complexity:

- Note that in each step, at least `size(A)/2` elements are removed
  (why?)
- This gives us the complexity of `O(d(n)) + O(d(n/2)) + O(d(n/4)) + ... + O(d(1))`
- In the above `O(d(n))` is the complexity of the optimal 'find all local maxima' algorithm (step 1).
- Now, given this fact, and assuming (towards contradiction) `d(n)` is in `o(n)`  [**small o notation**, `d(n)` is asymptotically 'weaker' than `n`)] - we get that `d(n) + d(n/2) + ... + d(1)` is in `o(n + n/2 + ... + 1) = o(2n) = o(n)`

So, we solved global maximum in `o(n)` algorithm, but it is `Omega(n)` problem - **contradiction**.

Thus, the algorithm in step 1 MUST be `Omega(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

amit's lower bound is correct but not as interesting as it could be, since the instances under consideration may have Omega(n) local maxima.

It turns out that, in the randomized cell-probe model of computation versus an oblivious adversary, even **finding a second local maximum requires Omega(n) probes in expectation**. Start with the array 1..n and choose one of the elements uniformly at random to be increased by 2. This makes a second local maximum (unless the last element is selected), with the first, of course, being the last element of the array. The algorithm does not learn anything about the location of the second local maximum until it probes the perturbed location. By Yao's lemma, some deterministic algorithm is optimal against this oblivious adversary, so the expected time to find the second local maximum is at least (n + 1)/2 probes.